# random data returns on android browser

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, frontend

I have an application that maps an array (that is in the state) that should really only have 6 sets of data in it (the back end really limits it to 6) but somehow this sometimes spikes and prints data that isn't there or is old.
It works perfectly fine on google chrome and more, but when it hits an old android browser it begins to have this error.
is it an es3 thing? I have web pack handling that (I thought).

```
{objects.map((object)=> {return <Data key={object.key} info={object}/> })}
```

that is where I provide data inside `<div>`
Is there something I need to do different via webpack for it to work on an android browser (which is es3 i believe).
It works perfectly on my google chrome browser and more.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack bundles your code, Babel is what compiles your code. You can change which browser version are targeted by editing your Babel configuration which is either in the package.json or .babelrc file.

To your specific issue, can narrow the realm of possibilities by creating a build that targets that version of Android to be sure.

Configuration would look something like [this](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/) in a `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": [ "Android >= 4" ]
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

And if your Babel config is in your `package.json`, then like [this](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/):

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      ["env", {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [ "Android >= 4" ]
        }
      }]
    ]
  }
}
```

Would find out the browser version of Android you are targeting and input that above.

I'd also look at the network traffic on the android device to be sure more than six records are not being received due to a malformed request or a bug in your API.

A browser bug can not make data appear. Leads me to believe this is an API bug. If you are seeing more than 6 records from an API that is constrained to 6 records, this means there is a bug in the API or 6 records are being retrieved at a time and added to an array held in memory. So the list keeps growing. Just some armchair suspicions/guesses.